# Streaming fullscreen with Open Broadcaster Software gives black screen

Tags: streaming, obs

After a long while i figured out how to stream in HD. However, every time I stream in fullscreen, the stream will show a black screen instead. If I stream a game in Windowed mode it will show it without any issues.

How can I stream a game in full screen mode for free so I can prevent them from seeing my desktop and give them the optimal quality resolution?

I'm using Open Broadcaster Software and have set my settings to entire screen. or are there better solutions?

Comment: well, you can use Shift window (http://grismar.net/shiftwindow/) for making windowed games look fullscreen. And it works with streaming. Used it for streaming League of Legends.

Comment: When you say "prevent them" - who is them?

Comment: @EBongo the viewers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Per Jim](http://sourceforge.net/p/obsproject/discussion/general/thread/fae8125f/) (listed as a Dev) on the Sourceforge Open Broadcaster Software Forum, OBS does not support fullscreen mode, but it is a planned future improvement.

> Currently, fullscreen games can't be captured via software means without using DXTory or something.
>
> Fortunately, I do have plans in the future to add fullscreen game capture, but because it's a rather difficult problem to tackle and will require a lot of time and focus, it's a bit lower on the priority list and won't be in for quite some time.

[DXtory](http://dxtory.com/v2-home-en.html) looks to be a non-free screen scraping application, and I'll go out on a limb and assume that's not what your looking for, as it would be a pretty advanced technical solution.

Others in the thread suggest [borderless fullscreen windowed](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Borderless_fullscreen_windowed#GameCompanion) mode as a workaround.  This would accomplish many of the goals you are shooting for, and would get around the OBS limitation.  If you follow that link there are a number of applications listed, including Shift which was mentioned in comments.  There is also some mention of potential drawbacks of each, such as compatibility with Punkbuster.

Finally, as this [PC Gamer article points out](http://www.pcgamer.com/2012/12/04/how-to-set-up-open-broadcaster-a-free-lightweight-livestreaming-application/), be sure that your source content is not minimized when you experience "black screen".

> You can now preview the stream or start broadcasting, but you won’t see anything if the game is minimized

If you are willing to entertain other options, [this video](http://youtu.be/gHNBCtdBMi4) describes how to setup [Xfire](http://www.xfire.com/) and [Twitchtv](http://www.twitch.tv/) for fullscreen mode games, and towards the end he shows proof that it works with Fifa '12.  Both are free services, but with Twitchtv your viewers may have to sit through some ads before watching, if they don't want to pay for the [ad free service](http://www.twitch.tv/products/turbo?ref=header).

Comment: Borderless fullscreen windowed seems to work. But its not the perfect solution since not all games have that option.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull up task manager in windows and go to hearthstone right click maximize and you will not see your desktop when you stream in obs. This does not let you stream full screen mode but it hides your desktop from being seen while you stream and play.
 Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about it myself, but I know a place that does: [Twitch](http://support.twitch.tv/discussion/4032/how-do-i-stream).

Their support page has more info, but the bit about software and how to set it up reads:

> Step 4: Decide on a streaming application. Your main options are [XSplit](http://www.xsplit.com/) ([free and paid](https://www.xsplit.com/Account/License/Buy/pp=NAVBAR)), [OBS](http://obsproject.com/), [FMLE](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-encoder.html), and [FFsplit](http://www.ffsplit.com/). XSplit, OBS and FFsplit includes built in desktop capturing while FMLE requires a 3rd party capturing software such as [SCFH DSF](http://koitsu.wordpress.com/2009/09/12/how-to-install-and-use-scfh-dsf/). We recommend starting with XSplit if you are new to steaming or OBS if you are looking for a totally free solution.
>
> Step 5: Set up your streaming software. There are already a large number of really good guide for this so I will just link them here. The basic steps include creating your connection to the TwitchTV server, configuring your quality and bandwidth settings, and configuring a capture of your desktop (PC) or from a capture card (console).
>
> - [Streaming 101](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=309480) by [TheGunrun](http://twitch.tv/thegunrun) [Hardware recommendations, XSplit, and capture card options] ** Recommended
> - [Complete XSplit Streaming Walkthrough](http://support.twitch.tv/discussion/2807/longtldr-complete-xsplit-streaming-walkthrough-screen-regiongamesourcedxtory) by [Fire](http://twitch.tv/fire) [XSplit Screen region/Gamesource, Dxtory]
> - [FFSplit Install Guide](http://www.ffsplit.com/?page_id=14)
> - [Beginner’s Guide to Desktop Streaming](http://www.destinysc2.com/newbies-guide-to-streaming/) by Destiny [FMLE, VHScrCap, VAC]
> - [Our Tutorial Section](http://support.twitch.tv/discussions) - Lots of misc. tutorials that are not listed here.
>
> Also, you may want to check out our [FAQ](http://support.twitch.tv/discussion/2391/frequently-asked-questions) as well.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to open the settings menu of the game (for example, League of Legends) and change the video output from full screen to windowed.

Specifically for League of Legends, I recommend borderless instead of windowed for best looking streaming.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Windowed Borderless mode in your game, or you can try to add the game via adding a new Game Capture from the sources pane.

Answer (score 0):

Just launch OBS in administrator mode and use game capture, some games in fullscreen also will require that to show it in window capture. But administrator mode for the win.

Answer (score 0):

Change how OBS is launched.  Right click OBS shortcut -> run with graphics processor -> integrated.  Done.

Answer (score -2):

I've been able to fix this issue a few times simply by refreshing the game window preferences.  Tutorial here:

Comment: Please summarize the video's content in your answer.  That way, if your video ever goes down, this answer can still help people.