# Is it possible to show HD TV screen as webcam on my laptop?

Tags: xbox-360, monitor, streaming

For online streaming purposes, is it possible to display what's being played on TV via the xbox 360 as webcam ? So that you can basically stream the gameplay live ?

I have two HDMI cables, one is from the laptop and the other from the Xbox 360, both connected to the HDTV.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What do you mean by "as webcam" exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound Basically have the HDTV screen output as a webcam option, so that you can choose it to be streamed rather than streaming the laptop's webcam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to my answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107162/21619), there are several options for streaming live gameplay.  Two noteable options would be [Open Broadcaster](http://sourceforge.net/projects/obsproject/files/latest/download) and [Xfire](http://www.xfire.com/) in combination with [TwitchTV](http://www.twitch.tv/) as shown in [this video](http://youtu.be/gHNBCtdBMi4).

Now the big catch is that you are going to need a lot of hardware to get the output from your XBox connected to a PC that can use these applications.  There is a pretty good walkthrough in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZIsWWqguKQ).

There are two main ways to go about this:

1. Split the HDMI out of your XBox and route one channel to your TV and one to a PC.
   You will need:

   - An HDMI splitter
   - PC with an HDMI input, typically via an add in graphics adapter (only input needed).     In the video they use an [Avermedia card](http://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=http://bit.ly/avermediagamebroadcasterhd&session_token=9rmhBBpiUB9vJZfbSK80fTTW6ON8MTM2Mjk4NjI2MkAxMzYyOTcxODYy)
   - 2 HDMI cables
2. Route your HDMI to a PC "capture card" like the [Black Magic Intensity](http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/intensity/) series.
   You will need:

   - The capture card of your choice (input and ouput)
   - A PC compatible with the capture card
   - 2 HDMI cables

I'm not sure which option is really cheaper or better.  I personally have a Black Magic card, but I mostly just record videos from it.  If you are sizing up a rig for doing some recording, do consider a fast SSD drive - as recording in high def requires fast storage access.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the video output of your xbox you will need a capture card. A capture card is like a video card, but it has a video in port, and software to capture the incoming signal. Depending on the software you use, you can then submit that video stream to for example xSplit to stream it to twitch. It all depends on the type of card you have and the combination of software you use though.

PS: You can not install a capture card in your laptop, so you will need a desktop for this. There are some external (usb etc) solutions, but they don't reach the same level of quality.

Comment: Its not fair to say its not possible to install a capture card.  Its entirely possible a mpci-express capture card exists.

Comment: @Ramhound A google search turned up with nothing. This leads me to believe that an mpci-express capture card is not commmon, and I would not suggest installing something in a laptop yourself if there are not much resources to be found on how to do it safely and without voiding warranty.